# translate js construct (object)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in my code i find this expression for axios

```
instanceAx.interceptors.request.use((config) => ({
 ...config,
}));
```

i can not understand and translate in old js this part of code ({...config}), I thought it was this:

```
//my dummy example
let config={config:{a:1,b:2}};
const test=(config) => {
  return (config)=>{...config}
 }
```

but i have always a error in compilate, some one can help me to find where i can understand this js construct and can help me to craete a dummy example of first code?

Another question, which is the differents from this with ():

```
 instanceAx.interceptors.request.use((params) => {
   console.log('params', params);
   console.log('params2', { ...params });
   return ({
     ...params,
   });
 });
```

and this without ():

```
 instanceAx.interceptors.request.use((params) => {
   console.log('params', params);
   console.log('params2', { ...params });
   return {
     ...params,
   };
 });
```

Comment: You forgot the parentheses: `(config)=>({...config})`

Comment: @Hao Wu,thanks but please enlarge your answer, your answer not work and not help me to understand. Please attach all code dummy for me, please

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @felix thanks, but it's the use of ({..blabla}) the problem. I know the spread operation, but why ({...myspred}) ?, it' s possible translate this in old js?write in function(..spread)

Comment: try to insert a simple console.log in some part of that function, i can not do it

Comment: add more examples to try explain my question

Comment: I think you are mixing up/confusing things, which makes it difficult to help you. I don't know which version of JavaScript you mean when you say "old JavaScript", and which parts you want to replace exactly. The reason for using parenthesis is not really related to object spread at all, it's because of the syntax of array functions. After `=>`, a `{` denotes the start of a multiline function body, not an object literal. The `()` are only needed to tell JavaScript to interpret the `{}` as an object literal. These are the same: `params => ({...params})` , `params => { return {...params}; }`.

Comment: There is no difference between `return {...params};` and `return ({...params});`. The `{` after the `return` keyword can only be the start of an object literal.